# Reading data from file with Python-special format

Tags: python

I have one problem. I have some data file which structure is that:

first line

```
219,241,280,369,402.7,472.7,520,553.3,588.7,635.3,678.7,734.7,795.3,880,914,968.7,1030.7,1085.3,1185.3
```

second line

```
436.5,430.5,426,418,420,413.3,410,406.7,404,402,407.3,410,413.3,418.7,420,428,433.3,440.7,458.7
```

In first line are values of x and in second line are values of y.
Now I want these values ​​to get into this shape:

```
x=r_[219,241,280,369,402.7,472.7,520,553.3,588.7,635.3,678.7,734.7,795.3,880,914,968.7,1030.7,1085.3,1185.3]

y=r_[436.5,430.5,426,418,420,413.3,410,406.7,404,402,407.3,410,413.3,418.7,420,428,433.3,440.7,458.7]
```

I have a problem with the addition of r_.
Any suggestion?

Comment: To make it clear: you want to literally store `x=r_[...]` in the file?

Comment: what did you try? Any code? and what is _r?

Comment: I dont used this method...to literally store in the file. I used some Jacobian solver for aproximation and this solver need values in shape r_[].

Comment: @Franta Konopnik it `I dont used this method...` what do you mean which method?

Comment: r_ add to a data file

Comment: @Franta Konopnik IMHO there is no such thing `r_add` maybe it's something you created at you code?

Comment: Yes r_ is in Jacobian solver. For proper function I must forward values of x and y in this format: x = r_[firstline of data file] and y = r_[secondline of data file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understand this correctly this is what you should do (assuming the name of the file is `test.txt`):

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    firstline = f.readline().rstrip("\n")
    secondline = f.readline().rstrip("\n")

firstline = "x=r_[" + firstline + "]\n"
secondline = "y=r_[" + secondline + "]\n"
data = firstline+secondline

with open("test2.txt", "w") as f:  # <-- changed name here, just in case
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

```
firstline = '436.5,430.5,426,418,420,413.3,410,406.7,404,402,407.3,410,413.3,418.7,420,428,433.3,440.7,458.7'
secondline = '436.5,430.5,426,418,420,413.3,410,406.7,404,402,407.3,410,413.3,418.7,420,428,433.3,440.7,458.7'

x = 'r_[' + firstline + ']'
y = 'r_[' + secondline + ']'
```

I really have no idea what you actually want...

Comment: yes this is it. but x = r_[ + firstline + ] and y = r_[+ secondline +]. So without apostrophes.